# Order by specific values in a column without using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I would like to get the records in the below format:

if i have a record like

```
A, B, C, D
```

and I would like get record in this order -

```
B, A, C, D, E, F, G, H, so on,
```

But I need the value `B` should be at the first row...

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use CASE?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
SELECT
    *, 1 AS SortBy 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YourCol='B'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *, 2 AS SortBy 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YourCol!='B'
    ORDER BY SortBy, YourCol
```

You don't give any reason to not want to use `CASE`.  I'd still give it a try and see which is faster, the `UNION ALL` or the `CASE` method:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourCol='B' then 1 ELSE 2 END, YourCol
```

**EDIT** Working example:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (YourCol char(1), RowValue varchar(5))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('A','aaa')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('A','aa')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('B','bbb')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('B','bb')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('C','ccc')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('D','ddd')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('E','eee')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('F','fff')

SELECT
    *, 1 AS SortBy 
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE YourCol='B'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *, 2 AS SortBy 
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE YourCol!='B'
    ORDER BY SortBy, YourCol
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourCol RowValue SortBy
------- -------- -----------
B       bbb      1
B       bb       1
A       aaa      2
A       aa       2
C       ccc      2
D       ddd      2
E       eee      2
F       fff      2

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Will that order by apply to the entire union or just the last select statement?

Comment: @alun, there is only one `ORDER BY` per `UNION` and it is on the last `SELECT`, and it will apply to the entire result set. [UNION (Transact-SQL), see example "C"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: A "funny" way to do it: SELECT column
FROM table
ORDER BY REPLACE(SUBSTRING(column,1,1),'B','')

Comment: I am using Union all between the select statements in the sProc and i am getting an error

Comment: @user878488, that is hardly enough info to go on to solve the error.  however, you should verify that you add an alias name onto the `1` and `2` columns (the `AS SortBy` part), and that each query of the `UNION` has the same number and type of columns.  see my latest edit, I've provided a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from mytable where mycolumn = "B";
```

followed by

```
SELECT * from mytable where mycolumn != "B" order by mycolumn asc;
```

Comment: If you mean union: union does not preserve the order, if you mean building the ordered result in code. Yes that works.

Comment: Yes, I did mean performing 2 queries and combining the results in code.

Comment: I am getting this Error - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and populate table:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col1 CHAR)
INSERT @t
SELECT char(number+ 65)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND number < 6
```

Query1:

```
SELECT *, cast(ascii(col1)-66 as bit) * 2 + ascii(col1) [orderby]
FROM @t 
ORDER BY cast(ascii(col1)-66 as bit) * 2 + ascii(col1)
```

Query2:

```
SELECT *
FROM @t 
ORDER BY replace(col1, 'B', ' ')
```

Result for Query1: (the [orderby] column is included for documentation only)

```
col1 orderby
---- --------
B    66
A    67
C    69
D    70
E    71
F    72
```